# update node impossible due to installed version

Tags: node.js, updates

I'm trying to update node:

```
npm update npm -g
```

Everything seems to be ok, but with the command:

```
npm -v
```

I've this version:

> 7.19.1

So I've tried to use the node .msi file with the latest lts (V14.17.3) and I've an error message saying that I've already the last version installed!

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm and node are different applications so they have different version numbers.
Check your node version with the command:

```
node --version
```